# Split string in python on basis of non-continuous integer, characters and float

Tags: python, regex, string

I have a string which has 4 sections with no white spaces:
[image]

The first section can have 3-5 letters followed by 6 digits followed by letter 'A' followed by a floating number. A typical string could be  **ABCD192014A82.5** 
 or,  **ABC192014A82.5**  or,  **ABCDE192014A82.5**

I would like to split this string into sub-strings as 'ABCD','192014','A' and '82.5'

I tried the following code but this works fine if the first section doesn't have 'A'. So, string **CDBF192014A82.5** gets segregated correctly but string **ADBF192014A82.5** has issues because, i guess, the first string has A itself. 
Any suggestions?

`re.match(r"([a-z]+)([0-9]+)", MyString.split('A')[0], re.I)`

Comment: Why are you splitting on A?

Comment: `re.match(r"([a-z]+)([0-9]+)A([0-9.]+))"`

Comment: Please show an attempt to build the full regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `re.split` with capture group:

```
l = ['ABCD192014A82.5', 'ABC192014A82.5', 'ABCDE192014A82.5']
for i in l:
    print(i, re.split('([A-Z]+)', i)[1:])
```

Output:

```
ABCD192014A82.5 ['ABCD', '192014', 'A', '82.5']
ABC192014A82.5 ['ABC', '192014', 'A', '82.5']
ABCDE192014A82.5 ['ABCDE', '192014', 'A', '82.5']
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
>>> for testcase in [
        'ABCD192014A82.5',
        'ABC192014A82.5',
        'ABCDE192014A82.5',
        'CDBF192014A82.5',
        'ADBF192014A82.5'
]:
    components = re.match(r'([A-Za-z]{3,5})(\d{6})(A)([0-9.]{3,4})', testcase).groups()
    print(testcase, *components, sep='\t')


ABCD192014A82.5 ABCD    192014  A   82.5
ABC192014A82.5  ABC 192014  A   82.5
ABCDE192014A82.5    ABCDE   192014  A   82.5
CDBF192014A82.5 CDBF    192014  A   82.5
ADBF192014A82.5 ADBF    192014  A   82.5
```

The parts of the regex are:

```
 [A-Za-z]{3,5}          # 3 to 5 letters
 \d{6}                  # 6 digit integer
 A                      # Letter 'A'
 [0-9.]{3,4}            # 3 to 4 digit float
```

Comment: Hi @Raymond, I am having issues with this implementation if the last number is 82 instead of 82.5. Maybe 82.0 would work but mentioning simply 82 seems to have a problem.

Comment: Change the last part of the regex from ``[0-9.]{3,4}`` to ``[0-9.]+``